# Ordering by specific field value first

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with 3 columns:

| id | name | priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | core | 10 |
| 2 | core | 9 |
| 3 | other | 8 |
| 4 | board | 7 |
| 5 | board | 6 |
| 6 | core | 4 |

I want to order the result set using `priority` but first those rows that have `name=core` even if have lower priority. The result should look like this

| id | name | priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | core | 4 |
| 2 | core | 9 |
| 1 | core | 10 |
| 5 | board | 6 |
| 4 | board | 7 |
| 3 | other | 8 |

Answer (score 265, accepted):

There's also the [MySQL `FIELD` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field).

If you want complete sorting for all possible values:

```
SELECT id, name, priority
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIELD(name, "core", "board", "other")
```

If you only care that "core" is first and the other values don't matter:

```
SELECT id, name, priority
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIELD(name, "core") DESC
```

If you want to sort by "core" first, and the other fields in normal sort order:

```
SELECT id, name, priority
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIELD(name, "core") DESC, priority
```

There are some caveats here, though:

First, I'm pretty sure this is mysql-only functionality - the question is tagged mysql, but you never know.

Second, pay attention to how `FIELD()` works: it returns the *one-based index* of the value - in the case of `FIELD(priority, "core")`, it'll return 1 if "core" is the value.  If the value of the field is not in the list, it returns *zero*.  This is why `DESC` is necessary unless you specify all possible values.

Comment: After about 5 years I changed accepted answer to this one because it's cleaner and faster.

Comment: db2 equivalent?

Comment: It worked for me, would like to ask one more question about how to handle If column 'priority' contains values like ex: 'earth core','new board' etc. Here column not containing an exact value, can we write something like %core%?

Comment: @JayanthSuvarna: looking at the MySQL FIELD() docs, I am pretty sure there isn't any way to evaluate this as substrings, as each argument has to be some kind of string.  There may be some string manipulation functions that could help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Omid - There are three answers here, each produces a different result.  Which one did you find "cleaner and faster"?

Comment: @RickJames In comparison to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104090/550042.

Comment: @Omid - Good.  I like that one, too.  I hope that is the one Leia wants to reward.  I don't think any other version will be faster.

Comment: I feel so weird, in my 21 years career I never had to do this! Now all of a sudden this saves me a bunch of unnecessary queries!
Thanks for teaching me something new! :-)

Answer (score 105):

Generally you can do

```
select * from your_table
order by case when name = 'core' then 1 else 2 end,
         priority
```

Especially in MySQL you can also do

```
select * from your_table
order by name <> 'core',
         priority
```

Since the result of a comparision in MySQL is either  `0` or `1` and you can sort by that result.

Comment: what does `1` and `2` means here?

Comment: I've around 3000 rows to sort. In my case the solution of @Ayman-Hourieh on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in takes half of the time compared to this solution.

Comment: @nightlyop: Good one. Only one note: The faster solution is MySQL-specific.

Comment: `1` and  `2` are just 2 numbers I use to sort the data. Could be `3` and `4` or something else.

Comment: What about when there is `%` in the `WHERE` clause? Like `. . . WHERE name LIKE '%sth%' . . .` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303379/how-can-i-sort-the-result-of-a-query-based-on-the-one-column

Comment: @stack: Not really related to this question. Ask another question with detailed explanation of your problem.

Comment: @juergend [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303379/how-can-i-sort-the-result-of-a-query-based-on-the-one-column)

Comment: Your method #1 is more useful than using FIELD() as you can add entries at the top of your results that aren't in DESC order.

Answer (score 6):

One way to give preference to specific rows is to add a large number to their priority.  You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
  select id, name, priority
    from mytable
order by priority + CASE WHEN name='core' THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END desc
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/753ee/1

Answer (score 6):

This works for me using Postgres 9+:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY name = 'core' DESC, priority DESC
```

Comment: Care to explain -1?

Error + Postgres version?

Answer (score 3):

One way is this:

```
select id, name, priority from table a
order by case when name='core' then -1 else priority end asc, priority asc
```

Comment: Won't this lose the order of the `core` rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM cars_new WHERE status = '1' and car_hide !='1' and cname IN ('Executive Car','Saloon','MPV+','MPV5') ORDER BY FIELD(cname, 'Executive Car', 'Saloon','MPV+','mpv5')
```

Comment: Although your code may be the answer to the question, it's better to provide some explanation about it.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column `name`+0 ASC
```

Appending the +0 will mean that:

```
0, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4
```

becomes :

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11
```

Comment: This technique is for turning a string into a number.  It does not address the OP's question.  (However, without seeing the datatype of `priority`, I can't say whether it _should be_ part of the complete solution.)

Answer (score -1):

**Use this:**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY priority desc, FIELD(name, "core")
```

Comment: This should have been `ORDER BY FIELD(name, "core") DESC, priority ASC`, so that we first look at the "name" field, and place the "core" values first.