# order by string exists in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I need to get some records from a mysql database and order them in a special order: some records have a special string and some don't. I need to put the ones who don't have this special string and than the ones who have. Is there a way using mysql like

```
SELECT * FROM mutable ORDER BY col_name, "special string not exists"
```

or do i have t odo it in php after getting the records without order?

Comment: can you please provide some sample data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With decode, you can convert one value to another.

```
SELECT * FROM mutable ORDER BY col_name, decode(column_with_sepcial_string, "special string", 1, 0)
```

Those who have the special string get a 1 as value, those who don't get a 0 (do note that `null` values always get `null` back).  When you order 0 and 1 ascending, the 0's (those who don't have the special string) are above the ones with a 1 (with the special string)