# MySQL order by text

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I know how I can sort by id or number like

```
$getTicket = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `ticket` 
                          WHERE `user`='$user->name' 
                          ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

I have Status in the ticket table, and in that I have 3 things:

1. Answered
2. Unanswered
3. Done

I want to sort it in this way:

1. Unanswered
2. Answered
3. Done

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: dupe of [Ordering by specific field value first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do simple as-

```
ORDER BY FIELD(Status, 'Unanswered', 'Answered', 'Done')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generally use `case`

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket` 
WHERE `user` = '$user->name' 
ORDER BY case when Status = 'Unanswered' then 1
              when Status = 'Answered' then 2
              else 3
         end
```

or MySQL specific `find_in_set`

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket` 
WHERE `user` = '$user->name' 
ORDER BY find_in_set(Status, 'Unanswered,Answered,Done')
```