# How can I sort mySQL data with a specific country ID first, followed by the normal order?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL data set like this:

```
id      | name      | country_id      | sort    |
-------------------------------------------------
0000001   Name A      2001              29.90
0000002   Name B      2929              90.02
0000003   Name C      2001              99.50
0000004   Name D      2001              42.03
0000005   Name E      2929              62.49
0000006   Name F      1005              78.00
```

Normally, I would do an `ORDER BY sort DESC` and then I'd get a result like:

```
0000003   Name C      2001              99.50
0000002   Name B      2929              90.02
0000006   Name F      1005              78.00
0000005   Name E      2929              62.49
0000004   Name D      2001              42.03
0000001   Name A      2001              29.90
```

Now, what I'd like to do is show the results of `country_id 2929` first, also ordered by `sort DESC`, followed by the other results in the `sort DESC` order as they would if there was no `country_id` order before.

How would I achieve that? So basically the order should be:

```
0000002   Name B      2929              90.02
0000005   Name E      2929              62.49
0000003   Name C      2001              99.50
0000006   Name F      1005              78.00
0000004   Name D      2001              42.03
0000001   Name A      2001              29.90
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have look here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `order by FIELD`

```
order by FIELD(country_id,'2929') DESC,sort DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
select
    id ,
    name ,
    country_id ,
    sort
from tbl
order by (case when country_id = 2929 then 1 else 0 end) DESC, sort DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another form of the previous answer:

select
    id ,
    name ,
    country_id ,
    if(country_id = 2929,0,1) as Country_Sort,
    sort
from tbl
order by  Country_Sort, sort DESC

Answer (score 0):

The shortest form is:

```
order by country_id=2929 DESC, sort DESC
```

country_id=2929 will be evaluated to 1 when it's true, and to 0 otherwise, so you can just order by `country_id=2929 DESC` to put the country 2929 at the top.