# Array sorting based on the string given

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, usort

I have a php array coming as result set from database.

as i am less familiar with mySQL sorting, i want to sort my result set based on the a particular string say "madhapur"

```
$arr=array(    
    array("name" => 'madhapur',"population" =>'1000'),
    array("name" => 'jubiliee hills',"population" =>'800'),
    array("name" => 'madhapur',"population" =>'900'),
    array("name" => 'adikmet',"population" =>'200'),
    array("name" => 'sr nagar',"population" =>'3000'),
    array("name" => 'jubilee hills',"population" =>'1200'),
    array("name" => 'madhapur',"population" =>'1000')   
    );
```

I am expecting the result as below

```
$arr=array(
array("name" => 'madhapur',"population" =>'1000'),
array("name" => 'madhapur',"population" =>'1000'),
array("name" => 'madhapur',"population" =>'900'),
array("name" => 'adikmet',"population" =>'200'),
array("name" => 'jubilee hills',"population" =>'1200'),
array("name" => 'jubiliee hills',"population" =>'800'),
array("name" => 'sr nagar',"population" =>'3000'),
);
```

I tried using usort but all of them are used to sort either descending or ascending.

```
function sortByName($a,$b){
         return $b['name'] - $a['name'];
    }
usort($arr,'sortByName');
```

Comment: So the only constraint is, arrays with `name` as `madhapur` should come at the beginning, right?

Comment: Why not sort it by MySQL? should be faster

Comment: to sort using mySQL i need to write stored procedure unless i can't pass name as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the name `madhapur` to the top and otherwise leave the order of elements as is/random:

```
usort($arr, function (array $a, array $b) {
    $a = $a['name'] == 'madhapur';
    $b = $b['name'] == 'madhapur';

    if ($a == $b || (!$a && !$b)) {  // both equal or both not madhapur
        return 0;
    } else if ($a) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

But this is really something that should be done in SQL.

Comment: i am wondering how to pass that madhapur to anonymous function in the usort. it is not static.

Comment: `function (..) use ($name) { .. }`, where `$name` is a variable in the current scope which holds 'madhapur'.

Answer (score 2):

First order by name and population in your sql, as your example appears to show everything ordered in that manner apart from the specific name (madhapur) promoted to the top

(note `DB` class is an example because i dont know what db access methods you use):

```
$arr = DB::Query("SELECT name, population 
                  FROM tablename 
                  ORDER BY name ASC, population DESC");
```

then you can iterate the array, and place the elements with the name you want at the beginning:

```
function nameAtFront($arr, $name){

    $copy = $arr;
    $total = count($arr);
    while($total--){
        if($copy[$total]['name']==$name){
            unset($arr[$total]);
            array_unshift($arr, $copy[$total]);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
$out = nameAtFront($arr, 'madhapur');
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: You could do this directly in SQL as well, which would probably be the best option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first

Comment: I know this but for this i need to write stored procedure to pass name as parameter. i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
$sorter=array();
$ret=array();
reset($array);
foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
    $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
}
asort($sorter);
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
    $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
}
$array=$ret;
}
```

for more detail take reference from 
Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value

Comment: Reference link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value