# How can I sort the result of a query based on the one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT name, usage_guidance, total_used_num
FROM tags
WHERE
( name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
  usage_guidance LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') ) AND
name NOT IN ($in)
LIMIT 6
```

Now I want to order the result by `name` column .. I mean I want to put the matched results because of `name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')` condition in first, and then other results should be after them. How can I do that?

Comment: `order by name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') desc, name asc`

Comment: @juergend Thank you, just can you please tell me why did you write `name asc` as second parameter of `order by` ?

Comment: To not only sort by first matches and then no-matches but to sort in those 2 groups by name. So all matches are sorted by name and after that the no-matches too.

Comment: @juergend I see, great .. seems you have lots of experiences about MySQL .. And my last request, can you please take a look at answer below which is written by Gordon? and tell me is his point of `where`, `order by`?

Comment: He is telling you to put the conditions of the `where` clause also in the `order by` clause with a  `desc` at the end. Basically the same as I said in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add the `where` conditions to the `order by` clause:

```
order by (name like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) desc,
         (usage_guidance LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')) desc
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions in a numeric context as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  Hence the `desc` order for the sorts.

Note that the second condition on `usage_guidance` is not strictly necessary to answer the question.

Comment: huh?! honestly your query is unclear for me .. what about the other part of  `WHERE` clause? `AND name NOT IN ($in)` ? And don't I need `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Well MySQL throws a syntax error .. it says: you cannot use `desc` in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @stack . . . That should have been `order by`.

Comment: Why did you avoid to add `AND name NOT IN ($in)` condition  *(which is one of `where` conditions)* to the `order by` clause?

Comment: @Shafizadeh . . . The question is about ordering.  That part is not relevant for ordering.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the results where `name LIKE %SOMETHING%` is matched displayed first.

You could achieve this by setting an additional select field <strike>in an `IF()` statement</strike> with the same condition as the `WHERE` clause for `name` and sort by that field:

```
SELECT name, usage_guidance, total_used_num, name LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%') as sort_field
FROM tags
WHERE
( name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
  usage_guidance LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') ) AND
name NOT IN ($in)
ORDER BY sort_field DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Edit: I just realized, you don't need the `IF()` statement at all