# Get all data and OrderBy specific word in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

How to get all data and orderBy specific word.
For example I have column name status. In the status is store for "Approved", "Pending","Rejected".

How can i sort the data like show all status "Pending" with descending order?

Comment: select  (case status when status= 'Pending' then 1 when status= 'Rejected' then 2 when status= 'Approved' then 3 end) as new_order from table order by new_order asc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
$data= DB::table('table_name')
                         ->orderby(DB::raw('case when status= "Pending" then 1 when status= "Rejected" then 2 when status= "Approved" then 3 end'))
                         ->get();
```

References
[Question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first) 
[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)