# Amazon Redshift order by specific values

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm new to Redshift and looking for a way to specify the order I want the results in, the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first) is exactly what I want, but the FIELD function does not exist in Redshift. Is there a way to accomplish the same result in Redshift?

Current Query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT audit_type, audit_category FROM "schema"."table"

ORDER BY audit_type,    
CASE WHEN audit_category = 'string_1' THEN 1 
  WHEN audit_category = 'string_2' THEN 2 
  WHEN audit_category = 'string_3' THEN 3 
  WHEN audit_category = 'string_4' THEN 4 
  WHEN audit_category = 'string_5' THEN 5 
  WHEN audit_category = 'string_6' THEN 6 
  WHEN audit_category = 'string_7' THEN 7 
ELSE 8 END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use CASE statement to achieve the same:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "name"='core' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, priority
```

you can extend the list with another option besides `core` by adding a new `WHEN / THEN` part before `ELSE`, so what you ultimately do is map a list of possible `name` options to integers that are used for sorting the rows

Comment: CASE
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_1' THEN 1
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_2' THEN 2
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_3' THEN 3
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_4' THEN 4
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_5' THEN 5
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_6' THEN 6
    WHEN audit_category = 'string_7' THEN 7
ELSE 8 END

I tried this, but it seems to still randomly order them?

Comment: @WillRoss it should sort, please post the entire query in the original question

Comment: Added current query into original question

Comment: @WillRoss in your example CASE statement should go first in the `order by` list if you want to prioritize ordering by that expression, and then `audit_type`

Comment: @WillRoss does this answer the question?

Comment: This solution works, I found the issue after some troubleshooting was in the strings being case sensitive. Not all of the categories followed the same case usage.