# Using ORDER BY FIELD and another (second) ORDER clause in one query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in) asks about specifying a sort order in MySQL.

What I'd like to do is have two levels of sort - the first would be my specified order, then the remaining, non-specified values would be sorted in the normal way.

What I tried is:

```
    SELECT
        version_id,
        version_name
    FROM
        software_versions
    ORDER BY 
        FIELD(version_id, 133, 41, 88), 
        version_name ASC
```

But what happens is the rows are sorted by version name, then FIELD (backwards from how the query is structured).

Is it possible to do what I am asking? The lookup table is relatively small (100 or so rows) so I'm not worried too much about the performance hit from using ORDER BY FIELD.

Do I need to rework this as a UNION?

Comment: Do you have version ids 133, 41 and 88? And can we assume versionid is a number field?

Comment: Add the FIELD clause to the SELECT list: what does it give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to reverse the order so `0` will always be in the last position.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(version, 88, 41, 133) DESC,  version_name ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb79cb/1)

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) explaining it. basically, because you haven't specified all of the version numbers, it won't work.  The work around is to sort by the field function, then the field itself.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(version, 88, 41, 133) DESC, version, version_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you haven't listed all of the possible values for version_id in your FIELD() function.

This should work though:

```
SELECT
    version_id,
    version_name
FROM
    software_versions
WHERE
    version_id IN (133, 41, 88)
ORDER BY 
    FIELD(version_id, 133, 41, 88), 
    version_name ASC
```