# Order by ? where col IN array

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to order the query result by the input array?

```
SELECT * FROM target_table WHERE id IN (4,2,6,1) ORDER BY ???
```

As you may notice this will give you a result order by the target_table ids and not necessary by the input array (4,2,6,1), is there a way to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - ORDER BY values within IN()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in)

Comment: Try using the `FIELD` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the array in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM target_table
WHERE id IN (4, 2, 6, 1)
ORDER BY field(id, 4, 2, 6, 1);
```

If you only want to list the numbers once, you can put the value in the `select` list and use `having`:

```
SELECT t.*, field(id, 4, 2, 6, 1) as ival
FROM target_table t
HAVING ival > 0
ORDER BY ival;
```