# Using FIELD() in ORDER BY clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

This is with reference to the answer given by [Ayman Hourieh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40005/)

to the question:
[MySQL - ORDER BY values within IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in)

```
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable
WHERE name IN ('B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
```

The FIELD function returns the position of the first string in the remaining list of strings.

It will thus be something like .. `ORDER BY 4` or `ORDER BY 1` as the `FIELD` function returns the position. Please explain how does `ORDER BY` work in this situation.

Comment: First of - please, explain us what do you want

Comment: `name` is field name by which you want to order result. The other is index of result how you want the order index.

Comment: "The FIELD function returns the position of the first string in the remaining list of strings" - that is wrong. FIELD function returns index of its non-first argument, which value matches the value of its first argument. For example `select FIELD('B', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')` will output `1`, `select FIELD('A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')` will output `2` and so on. So you can order by integer index returned by FIELD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row, `FIELD()` returns an integer value.
The rows are then ordered by this value.

Adding the `FIELD()` clause to the select part should help you understand how it works:

```
SELECT id, name, FIELD(name, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
FROM mytable
WHERE name IN ('B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
```

Sample result set:

```
 4 | Z | 0
12 | B | 1
 1 | B | 1
 6 | A | 2
 3 | E | 4
```

Comment: SELECT id, name
FROM mytable
WHERE name IN ('B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
ORDER BY 1

will give results ordered by column no. 1 (i.e. id) in the SELECT clause.


Similarly, 
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable
WHERE name IN ('B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
ORDER BY 2

will give results ordered by column no. 2 (i.e. name) in the SELECT clause.

Hence, the question.

Comment: Oh I see, you are getting confused because `ORDER BY [litteral integer]` has a different effect than `ORDER BY [integer expression]`.  Consider this query: `SELECT col FROM tab ORDER BY col`. The result set will be ordered by `col`, even if `col` is numeric. Perhaps [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3019a/3) will help.