# How to implement order by field value with jOOQ's dynamic queries

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I am trying to convert something like this in jOOQ:

```
select foo from bar
order by field(foo, 'value1', 'something-else', 'value3')
```

on a select query, like:

```
SelectQuery<Record> query = ...
query.addSelect(BAR.FOO);
query.addFrom(BAR);
query.addOrderBy( ... ? ... )
```

How does one add the last bit?

---

*Background*

What I am trying to accomplish is basically described here: [MySQL - ORDER BY values within IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in). In my case, I have a generic batch load function that uses 'where field in(..)' and I want to preserve order. This works as I need it to using plain SQL, but I need to add this bit to a dynamically constructed query with jOOQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you hit jOOQ's limits, resort to [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). You can write your own field function like this:

```
class MyDSL {

    public static Field<Integer> field(Field<String> search, String in1) {
        return field(search, DSL.val(in1));
    }

    public static Field<Integer> field(Field<String> search, Field<String> in1) {
        return DSL.field("field({0}, {1})", Integer.class, search, in1);
    }

    public static Field<Integer> field(Field<String> search, 
                                       String in1, 
                                       String in2) {
        return field(search, val(in1), val(in2));
    }

    public static Field<Integer> field(Field<String> search, 
                                       Field<String> in1, 
                                       Field<String> in2) {
        return DSL.field("field({0}, {1}, {2})", Integer.class, search, in1, in2);
    }

    // ... or, support a varargs function variant, too
}
```

And now use that in all your statements:

```
query.addOrderBy( MyDSL.field(BAR.FOO, "value1", "something-else", "value3") );
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the trick. Not sure if there is a better answer,

```
Field[] args = new Field[]{DSL.field("foo"), 
      DSL.val("value1"), DSL.val("something-else"), DSL.val("value3")}
query.addOrderBy(DSL.function("field", SQLDataType.INTEGER, args));
```

Comment: Yep, `DSL.function` works just as well as templating with `DSL.field()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like to convert following sql to jooq. Here 'sortAsc' is used to sort according to the given value order.

**SQL**

```
select foo from bar order by field(foo, 'value1', 'something-else', 'value3')
```

**JOOQ**

```
DSL()
.select(BAR.FOO)
.from(BAR)
.orderBy(BAR.FOO.sortAsc('value11', 'something-else', 'value3'))
.fetch()
```