# How to order the ORDER BY using the IN() mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to order the results by how the values in `IN()` clause are set up, here is the example code.

```
SELECT nickname, age WHERE id IN(3, 1, 2) ORDER BY ?; <- this is where I need the results go back according to the IN() clause
```

This the result as of now, (using PHPmyadmin, not yet php coded).

```
nickname | age | true id of the row
j        | 11  | 1
jj       | 22  | 2
jjj      | 33  | 3
```

The result that I need is:

```
nickname | age | true id of the row
jjj      | 33  | 3
j        | 11  | 1
jj       | 22  | 2
```

Can I do this with using `IN()` clause? This is the only idea that I came up with so if you have any idea/s that I may try then please tell me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](http://stackoverflow.com/a/396771/5447994)

Comment: thank you, that are greate answers, how can I close this and make this question officially duplicate?