# mysql - custom order with IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

my query is:

```
select * from table where id IN (1,5,4,3,2)
```

what I want is exactly same as this order not from 1...5 but 1,5,4,3,2.
How can I do that?

Comment: what you mean  for custom order ? any specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql)

Comment: Exact duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL's FIELD function and ORDER BY can help out here.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE 
 id IN (1,5,4,3,2)
ORDER BY 
 FIELD(id, 1,5,4,3,2)
```

**negatieve**  FIELD(id, 1,5,4,3,2) can't make use of the index on id column.

Or without the function FIELD

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
   1 AS number
  UNION 
  SELECT 
   5 AS number
  UNION 
  SELECT 
   4 AS number
  UNION 
  SELECT 
   3 AS number
  UNION 
  SELECT 
   2 AS number
) 
 AS numbers
INNER JOIN 
 [table]
ON
 [table].id = numbers.number
```

**positive** can use a index on id column. 
**negative** harder to understand because of the delivered table

Comment: only for this query :(, it may some more than 100 rows means what we do?